# Homology of $T^3$ generated by three copies of $T^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cross-product

Why is the second homology of $T^3=S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ generated by $S^1\times S^1\times \{\mathrm{pt}.\}$, $S^1\times \{\mathrm{pt}.\}\times S^1$ and $ \{\mathrm{pt}.\}\times S^1\times S^1$?

$H_2(T^3;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $H_2(T^2;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$, so that fits already nicely. But how does one actually prove some collection of homology classes is a generator of a homology group?

Comment: Presumably you're given some actually computable definition of homology, like simplicial or cellular. In that case you check it by writing down the explicit chain complex, and picking out cycles representing each homology class.

Comment: I have never done something like this so this is a little helpful, but not very much. So it is not possible with the axiomatic defintion?

Comment: How did you calculate the homology in the first place?

Comment: "Hence $H_n(X\times S^k; \mathbb{Z})\approx H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}) \oplus H_{n−k}(X; \mathbb{Z})$" in Hatcher`s book (page 272), case $k=1$